# How should I clean fabric that a mouse has been in?

Tags: cleaning, pest, mice

A mouse recently got into one of my cabinets. There was a cloth in one of those cabinets, and the mouse may have touched it or pooped on it.

**How should I clean this cloth?**

Is the washing machine enough?

I'm in the US midwest, in an urban area but we get a lot of critters like raccoons and stuff coming around. I mention that in case it's relevant to the regional diseases.

Comment: Do you have any pets? Do they ever go outdoors? If so, how do you clean fabric which they've been on?

Comment: Good question. I don't do anything special beyond normal cleaning, unless something crazy happens like poop or they got into something. I think you're implying that the same approach works here, but is that really true? I would think that mice carry more or different pathogens compared to pets.

Comment: Many people keep mice as pets. They don't constantly scrub everything in their house just because it's a mouse. Even if a dog defecates in the house, you simply pick it up, then give the carpet a quick scrub with carpet cleaner. You can most certainly bleach your fabrics "just to be sure", but then you'll end up with bleach stains and have to head to [lifehacks.se] to figure out how to repair those. Throw the cloth in the washer and be done with it. Or, live your life in fear of everything, [Mr. Monk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk_(TV_series)).

Comment: It being a mouse isn't the problem, it's that it lives outside where there's other life with, or that *are*, diseases. That being said, if pathogens really were some sort of huge concern, all plumbers would get hazard pay. - You're new to the Mid West? Yeah, it just gets cold here. We don't have any regional diseases except hay fever when it isn't. - You're up to date on your rabies and tetanus? Okay, enjoy the weather.

Comment: Launder. Animal stains, if there are any, are animal stains.